# What is '_get_val_from_obj' mechanic does?

Tags: django, django-geoposition

I am new to tooling job. Currently my favorite package in Django is outdated and seems no one care by now. Therefore I would like to study it.

**Problem:**
https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition/issues/100

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 95, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 494, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 454, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 491, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 22, in create
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 537, in data
    ret = super(Serializer, self).data
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 504, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1858, in to_representation
    return self.model_field.value_to_string(obj)
  File "/Users/sarit/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/poink/src/django-geoposition/geoposition/fields.py", line 50, in value_to_string
    value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
AttributeError: 'GeopositionField' object has no attribute '_get_val_from_obj'
```

**Official Docs:**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/

> Field._get_val_from_obj() is removed.

**Question:**
How to solve this error?

```
def value_to_string(self, obj):
    value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
    return smart_text(value)
```

**Update:**
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1865 
@linaskilius says

> Django recommends using the Field.value_from_object() instead.

**My Fork:**
https://github.com/elcolie/django-geoposition